# How to get the REAL iframe source after the submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

i've connected an iframe for payment.

```
<iframe src="https://direct.tranzila.com/xxxx/iframe.php?ppnewwin=2&lang=il&nologo=1&sum=9&pdesc=simple&currency=1&userid=123" name="tranzila_payment" id="tranzila_payment" width="370" height="455"></iframe>
```

Now after the payment succeed, the iframe redirect to success.php page.

I want to check it from the parent window. but $('#tranzila_payment').attr('src') have the same value (iframe.php).

Is it any other way to check if the iframe redirected to the goal page?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The `src` attribute stays as it was on page load even when the iframe moves to a new location, to get the current location you need to go get it from the window object within the iframe. Try this:

```
document.getElementById('tranzila_payment').contentWindow.location.href
```

Worth noting that anything you access through `iframe.contentWindow` is read-only.